# Unable to restore the postgresql data through command prompt

Tags: postgresql, data-import

I am trying to restore the postgres sql data from a file . I am trying to do so but it is not importing .

Here is the command which i am using:

postgres-# psql -hlocalhost -p5432 -u postgres -d test  -f  C:/wamp/www/test/database_backups/backup004.sql

Please help me what I am doing wrong . 
I am using windows and the above command does not throws any error but it does not import data.

Regards
Surjan

Comment: Does it produce any output at all? What do the contents of backup004.sql look like, how was it generated? Do you see any interesting messages in the postgresql log (typically in /var/log/postgresql/ in posix, don't know where they go on windows)?

Comment: Does it matter that you're using forward slashes in your filepath on a Windows server?

Answer (score 1):

The only immediate thing I can see there is the capitilsation of `-u` for username (should be `-U`).

**Correction:** You're typing the command line into the psql shell.

You should exit to the CMD.EXE shell, and try the command there.  With the correct capitalisation of `-U`, by the way.

OR, use this to replay the script into that psql shell:

```
\i C:/wamp/www/test/database_backups/backup004.sql
```

The forward slashes don't cause a problem on my Windows machine.